# What CSS positioning is best to use when creating a responsive website?

Tags: css

I'm just getting familiarized with CSS, however I am having a hard time figuring out what 'positioning' to use for a responsive website. The closest I got was by using 'absolute' positioning but it could not adjust to the different screen sizes. Any ideas?

Comment: "The closest I got was by using 'absolute' positioning but it could not adjust to the different screen sizes." — Yes, it can.

Comment: How would you go about doing that?

Comment: Percentage unit lengths and/or media queries, just like any other positioning scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a layout with all the elements being `absolute` positioned is certainly not a good idea.

You should really use floats.

To make it responsive you can apply percentage based widths to your elements instead of pixels, but really, the best way of doing it would be using CSS Media Queries, and changing the width as required.

Have a look at this article: 
[Quick Tip: A Crash-Course in CSS Media Queries](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-a-crash-course-in-css-media-queries/)
[Adaptive layouts with media queries](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/adaptive-layouts-media-queries)
[Responsive Web Design: A Visual Guide](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/responsive-web-design-a-visual-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

This site might help you understand the different values and behaves of position and how it works also use the "Play it" buttons and play around with the css to see the reaction and try to find what you are looking for.

Also position has nothing to do with the element's size only how the elements are positioned on the screen and from where to set the 0,0 coordinates

hope this helps